# Calculate the derivative of a scalar function w.r.t its vector argument?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vectors

If $J$ is a scalar function of two vectors $\boldsymbol{q}$ and $\boldsymbol{g}$:

$$J(\boldsymbol{q},\boldsymbol{g})=\frac{\boldsymbol{g\cdot g}}{\boldsymbol{q\cdot q}}.$$

How do I calculate the derivative $\frac{\partial J}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}}$?

What I have tried:

$$\frac{\partial J}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}}\left(\frac{\boldsymbol{g\cdot g}}{\| \boldsymbol{q} \|^2} \right)=-2\|\boldsymbol{q}\|^{-3} \boldsymbol{g\cdot g}=-2 \|\boldsymbol{q}\|\:( \boldsymbol{g\cdot g}) \|\boldsymbol{q}\|^{-4}=-2\|\boldsymbol{q}\|\: (\boldsymbol{g\cdot g}) (\|\boldsymbol{q}\|^{2})^{-2}\\=-2\|\boldsymbol{q}\|\:( \boldsymbol{g\cdot g}) (\boldsymbol{q\cdot q})^{-2}.$$

I am sure that my answer is wrong because it should have been a vector instead of a scalar.

For your reference, the answer given is

$$\frac{\partial J}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}}=-2\boldsymbol{q}( \boldsymbol{g\cdot g})/(\boldsymbol{q\cdot q})^2.$$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since $g\cdot g$ and $q\cdot q$ are just numbers, when you take the partial derivative of the denominator, use the quotient derivative, or, instead, think the escalar function as $J(q,g)=(g\cdot g)\cdot(q\cdot q)^{-1}$ and use the product derivative.

Comment: Thanks, however $\frac{\partial J}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}}$ should be a vector, right? @manooooh could u pls show your derivation explicitly?

Comment: $$\partial J/\partial q=(g\cdot g)\cdot(-2)\cdot(q\cdot q)^{-2}\cdot (q\cdot q)'=-2q(g\cdot g)/(q\cdot q)^2.$$ I can't really answer if the partial derivative is a vector... We should study what is the meaning of $\partial/\partial q(q\cdot q)$ (remember $q\cdot q$ is just a scalar product, i.e. a number).

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't mean "derivative product" but "chain rule". Think about $d/dx(y/x)$.

Comment: @manooooh if you thought of $\boldsymbol{q\cdot q}$ as a scalar, where does the coefficient (-2) come from? Isn't it $\frac{\partial J}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}}=(\boldsymbol{g\cdot g})\color{red}{(-1)}(\boldsymbol{q\cdot q})^{-2}\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} \boldsymbol{q}}(\boldsymbol{q\cdot q}))$ ?

Comment: Sorry again, I'm very uncomfortable at phone... $q$ is a variable-vector, then $$(q\cdot q)=\|q\|^2.$$ So when you take the derivative of that number you get the $2$. Maybe you want to expect other users to collaborate...

Comment: Regarding the L2 norm squared of a vector thinking it a s $a \dot a = a^H a=a^H I a$ may be helpful. The derivative of the norm squared wrt the vector then becomes $Ia+I^Ha=2a$

Comment: @keoxkeox did u mean $\boldsymbol{a\cdot a}$? What did u mean by 'H', is it conjugate transpose?

Comment: Yes, I meant the dot product and Hermitian I have just realized my typo and cannot edit now :( . Anyway as a final thing, I wanted to share The matrix cookbook with you: https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf it is a great collection of stuff regarding many things matrix/vector calculus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The partial derivative of a scalar w.r.t. a vector is a vector. Take partial derivative w.r.t. every element of the vector and put these together to get your result. Assuming that elements of $q$ are not depending on each other or a common parameter:
$$\frac{\partial J}{\partial q_i}=\frac{\partial}{\partial q_i}\left(\frac{\boldsymbol{g\cdot g}}{\| \boldsymbol{q} \|_2^2} \right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial q_i}\left(\frac{\boldsymbol{g\cdot g}}{\sum_k q_k^2} \right)$$
If $q$ and $g$ do not depend on a common parameter then $\boldsymbol{g\cdot g}$ is nothing but a constant
$$\frac{\partial J}{\partial q_i}=\boldsymbol{g\cdot g}\frac{\partial}{\partial q_i}\left(\frac{1}{\sum_k q_k^2 } \right)=-\boldsymbol{g\cdot g}\left({\sum_k q_k^2 }\right)^{-2}2q_i$$

$$\frac{\partial J}{\partial \boldsymbol{q}}=-2\boldsymbol{q}\frac{\boldsymbol{g\cdot g}}{\left(\boldsymbol{q\cdot q}\right)^2}$$
Hope this helps

Comment: This is a textbook-style demonstration, thanks!